# xquery/xpath comparing all but a specific node

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I have two documents I want to compare, but I want to omit comparison of two nodes that I know will be different, e.g.:

```
<record>
   <core>
      <title>test1</title>
      <description>testDesc1</description>
      <ingestDate>2019-03-01</ingestDate>
   </core>
   <specialized>
      <item>testItem1</item>
      <itemRecordingTime>2019-12-05T08:15:00</itemRecordingTime>
   </specialized>
</record>
```

and

```
<record>
   <core>
      <title>test1</title>
      <description>testDesc1</description>
      <ingestDate>2020-03-01</ingestDate>
   </core>
   <specialized>
      <item>testItem1</item>
      <itemRecordingTime>2020-12-05T08:15:00</itemRecordingTime>
   </specialized>
</record>
```

Is there any way in xquery or xpath to compare these two documents except for the nodes `<ingestDate>` and `<itemRecordingTime>`?

Comment: What kind of comparison do you want to do (`deep-equal`?), which result (simply true for equality and false if not?) do you want to get?

Comment: I would normalize the content first (remove the elements that you don't want to compare), and then perform the comparison.

Comment: Yes, deep equal.  Removing the elements first might be a good idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would normalize the content, removing the elements that you don't want to compare, and then use [`fn:deep-equal()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-deep-equal) to compare the normalized documents.

Below is an example of how you can use XSLT to remove the elements with [`xdmp:xslt-eval()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:xslt-eval) (you could also [`xdmp:xslt-invoke`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:xslt-invoke) an installed stylesheet instead of eval):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare function local:compare($a, $b) {
  let $xslt := 
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
      <!--Remove the elements that we don't want to compare -->
      <xsl:template match="ingestDate | itemRecordingTime"/>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
  let $normalized-a := xdmp:xslt-eval($xslt, $a)
  let $normalized-b := xdmp:xslt-eval($xslt, $b)
  return fn:deep-equal($normalized-a, $normalized-b)
};

let $doc-a := 
<record>
   <core>
      <title>test1</title>
      <description>testDesc1</description>
      <ingestDate>2019-03-01</ingestDate>
   </core>
   <specialized>
      <item>testItem1</item>
      <itemRecordingTime>2019-12-05T08:15:00</itemRecordingTime>
   </specialized>
</record>
let $doc-b :=
<record>
   <core>
      <title>test1</title>
      <description>testDesc1</description>
      <ingestDate>2020-03-01</ingestDate>
   </core>
   <specialized>
      <item>testItem1</item>
      <itemRecordingTime>2020-12-05T08:15:00</itemRecordingTime>
   </specialized>
</record>

return
  local:compare($doc-a, $doc-b)
```

Comment: It can sometimes be useful to use XSLT to also normalize whitespace in the XML. I would typically use strip-space on all elements, and allow the parser to indent the result. Note that you might need to serialize the result to get the whitespace normalization..

Answer (score 0):

Alternative. You can use XPath to extract the text nodes and concat them. Store the results in 2 variables and make the comparison.

XPath 2.0 :

```
string-join(//*/*[position()<last()]/text()[normalize-space()])
```

or

```
string-join(//*[not(name()="ingestDate" or name()="itemRecordingTime")]/text()[normalize-space()])
```

Output :

```
String='test1testDesc1testItem1'
```

XPath 1.0 (massive) :

```
translate(concat(substring(normalize-space(string(//core)),1,string-length(normalize-space(string(//core)))-(string-length(normalize-space(string(//ingestDate)))+1)),substring(normalize-space(string(//specialized)),1,string-length(normalize-space(string(//specialized)))-(string-length(normalize-space(string(//itemRecordingTime)))+1)))," ","")
```

Output :

```
String='test1testDesc1testItem1'
```